# Can I track session duration of a specific user-id via Google Analytics?

Tags: ios, session, google-analytics

I have an iOS app with Google Analytics to track engagement/retention, and I have been trying to set up a way to track the session durations of specific users. I followed all of the steps to send the User-ID value when a user logs into a session (using &uid), and I have also created a User-ID enabled reporting view. However, I have no idea how to sift through the bulk session data to pick out the behavior of an individual user. Thanks for your time and help, this is really important to my company.

Answer (score 1):

[User ID - iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/user-id)

> The User ID feature enables the measurement of user activities that
>   span across devices in Google Analytics, such as attributing an
>   interaction with a marketing campaign on one mobile device to a
>   conversion that occurs on another mobile device or in the browser.
>
> When User IDs are sent with Google Analytics hits using the userId
>   field, your reports will reflect a more accurate count of unique users
>   and offer new cross-device reporting options.

Userid is used internally by Google analytics to [give you more actuate user data](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123663) in your reports, there for your reports already have it included.

If you are trying to find the value itself so that you can track a user though their use of your application you cant.  Google Analytics doesn't allow you to track individual users that would violate their privacy.    You could add this value as a custom dimension and track them that way as long as its a non identifiable userid you are using, something that cant be tracked back to a specific user.